# Javascript If Condition not evaluating correctly

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a section of code where a variable contains a particular string (here it's `multiply`), and when I check if the variable has that particular string, the condition always equates to `false`. I cannot find what I'm missing here.

```js
 // calculations
$scope.$watch('colInput.' + el.key, function () {
  angular.forEach($scope.colInput[el.key], function (item, index) {
    angular.forEach($scope.column[el.key], function (item_1, index_1) {
       if (item.hasOwnProperty(item_1.key)) {
           item[item_1.key].type = item_1.type;
           item[item_1.key].id = item_1.id;
           item[item_1.key].options = item_1.options;
       } 
       else {
            item[item_1.key] = {};
            item[item_1.key].type = item_1.type;
            item[item_1.key].id = item_1.id;
            item[item_1.key].options = item_1.options;
       }
    })

    angular.forEach(item, function (elem, key) { //each column of the row
       var operand_1, operator, operand_2;
       if (elem.type == 10) {
       // analyzing the formula
       elem.options.forEach(function (el, index) {
           if (isNaN(el) && index == 1) {
             operator = el;
           } else if (isNaN(el) && index == 0) {
                operand_1 = el;
           } else if (isNaN(el) && index == 2) {
                operand_2 = el;
           } else if (!isNaN(el)) {
                operand_2 = parseFloat(el);
           }
       })
       console.log(operator, eval(operator === "multiply"), typeof operator);

       if (operator == 'multiply') {
           console.log("IF---")
           elem.value = parseFloat(item[operand_1].value) * operand_2;
        }
    }
   })
  })
}, true)
```

Comment: Have you attached a debugger in your favorite browser's Developer Tools? It can be incredibly helpful.

Comment: What do you get when you log the `operator` variable to the console ?

Comment: You're calling `isNaN` on an html element? That will *never* be true.

Comment: This code is full of bad practices: unnecessary `eval`, using `parseFloat` with no radix, using `window.isNaN` instead of `Number.isNaN`, etc...

Comment: when 'operator' is consoled, its displaying "multiply". and why is the 'operator' and HTML element?. I know the code is full of bad practices. sorry for that. and what is parseFloat with no radix??

Comment: I have found the issue. apparently " abc" != "abc". there was a whitespace.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your `operator` is an HTML element not a String. 
The comparison with `multiply` will always be false.

Comment: why do you say its and HTML Element. I have specifically declared that variable. what am I missing here. Excuse me for this lack of knowledge.

Comment: You have explicitly defined `operator`, but you assign the value of `el` to it. let's debug : what is `el` ? what do you get when you debug your `operator` variable in the console ?

Comment: the 'el' has value of  `'multiply' , 'amount', '19'` and when i console the `operator` . i get 'multiply'.